# No furniture bench in main hall despite several attempts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm trying to build the Lakeview house and no matter what, the furniture bench doesn't want to appear in the main hall.

I'm not using a steward.

I'm able to decorate the entry way and the east and north and south wings and the basement, but simply no furniture in the main room where the fireplace and the table is supposed to be, also no furniture upstairs, no double bed, no kids beds, nothing, and no bench in the back room of main hall.

I have tried adding and removing benches from the bench outside with no luck.

I've even started a new game, because I don't want an unfinished house hanging around on my map, on the New save I still experience the same problem.

Is there any way to fix this?